# What makes a deity?

Tags: internal-consistency, religion, gods

Under the assumption that there is a Creator God of unlimited power over the mortal universe and all dimensions and alternate realities that make up Creation (in my mental 'mythology,' this God is the same as many Creators in most religions, but interpreted and revered differently), my idea was to also include omnipotent beings other then God. Because they are also a part of Creation, they are limited by God, and at his whim do not usually make themselves known to mortals.
Part of this idea is to have certain mortals become powerful enough to apotheosize into deities, such as Moloch.
But is it plausible? Could there really be a setting where deities other then the main, monotheist God, exist without being created by Him? How would they have come into existence? What would their functions be?

To more clearly ask my question:
1. How would these deities form?
2. What would they do?
3. What would they consist of as sentient but nonhuman beings (though sometimes in physical form)?

Comment: I think the question of "what is a god" doesn't really belong here

Comment: I think the answers to these questions are mostly up to you. Gods, pretty much by definition, cannot be fully understood by humans, all you really have to do is point that out and gods could just *be* however you want them to. Anything is possible. Any answers we give would just be writing the story for you, which is not what this site is for.

Comment: If I were to include deities of my own, I don't want to go over any 'boundaries' in terms of realistic existence. And I certainly don't want to create a fictional personified concept that offends people.

Comment: `omnipotent beings` that are `limited by God` is a contradiction.

Comment: @Naos, I think you need to read some Greek, Roman and Norse mythology and see what their gods got up to.

Comment: The only beings I would consider gods are those that can violate the laws of thermodynamics.

Comment: As noted, there are a great many answers that might fit. I suggest you look up the phrase "deus otiosus" and see whether the many examples of this mythological pattern help you. If they don't answer the question, they should at least help you to refine it precisely.

Comment: @SJuan76 - I made that very confusing; I mean that The Creator allows them a certain degree of power so they can preform their duties, but are not powerful enough to defy Him. He may not have created them by hand, but they were produced 'out of Creation,' which makes The Creator their only authority. If The Creator decides to make one of them mortal, then nobody but The Creator can change that. The Creator could make them as powerful as Himself... but I don't really see that happening. (also, I am very intrigued by CAgrippa and this 'deus otiosus' and will greatly consider it.)

Comment: Also the last part of my question regards, essentially, the 'essence' of these gods. While The Creator would most likely be of similar essence, I guess I'm looking for a reason this essence would be conscious and moving, yet incorporeal. Mainly to introduce metaphysical conflicts and concepts into the story.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps Creator God is just the most powerful have a powerful race of spiritual beings. 
It would be easier to explain this if I used us as an example suppose you have a great artist that creates a magnificent painting. Then you have other people who are of the same race as the artist but don't have his skill. They still have some skill maybe almost on a level with artists others could barely make stick figures. The artist in this example is your Creator God the painting is the universe and everyone in it and the other lesser gods are everyone else. Overtime the other gods might become interested in our universe just like we would become interested in a painting that someone else made this might create a conflict between God creator and lesser gods as he might not appreciate their involvement in something he made. I'm not sure if I'm explaining this clear enough.

Answer to  question 1 in this example your lesser gods would  would be of the same race as your Creator. So whenever origin story for him with parallel there's. Except for the creation of the world of course.

Answer answer the question 2. Depends on the God but I assume that most would want to Explorer the universe and interactive humans and other created creatures maybe even doing things to them see how they react.  Depending on what they do they might find themselves coming into conflict with the Creator God.

don't understand question 3 could you try to explain?

Okay to answer your questions. First let me divide the minor gods. Into major and minor among themselves. They'd all be minor gods in compared to Creator God. But They probably would also have hierarchies among themselves.  Among their own hierarchies if I were you I would follow the example and in most mythology and have 12 major or ruling gods and hundred or so minor gods who are mostly aligned with one of the 12.  But that's just me you can follow any mold you like determine the number of lesser duties.

As for their interaction with mortals, since they did not create this world I can see most of thier interaction come from sheer curiosity about this new creation. For example they might appear for a large crowd and demand worship not because they  care what mortals think of them, but because they are curious as to how the mortals will react when they do. Curiosity however might be kept in check by their Creator God .

I could easily see these lesser gods coming into conflict with Creator God. They might for example introduce an idea into humanity out of curiosity to see what they will do with it. But for whatever reason this idea runs contrary to whatever plans Creator God has for his creation.

As for why they are here as soon they would be interested in us just like we would be interested in a master painting like the Mona Lisa especially if these lesser gods had not managed to create a universe on their own or ifbefore the creation of our universe they had tried to create a universe on there but failed.

Comment: I think I understand. What you're saying is that The Creator could be the most powerful of these unfamiliar deities, despite them being the same type of 'sentience' as Him, because the world they all exist in is **_His_** created world?

Comment: Yeah pretty much.

Comment: Intriguing... very helpful, thank you @Bryan McClure. But now to consider how and why the other gods are here, the roles the gods play, and why they would make themselves known to mortals.

Comment: @user16492 You got an answer for it?